# numpy image float array, to int 0..255 value

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, opencv

I got 3 NumPy data arrays r,g,b  represented as a 2D float64 array (720x1024)
Essentially per row, each channel is a bunch of floats:

```
[[0.94984896 0.96076077 0.9599071  ... 0.80338298 0.80253267 0.80560301], 
 [0.94958899 0.95265769 0.95964721 ... 0.80312296 0.80619422 0.80534302], 
 [0.94932439 0.95239315 0.95938273 ... 0.80285821 0.80592952 0.80115679], ..., 
 [0.97768162 0.98087441 0.98014583 ... 0.87006474 0.87325722 0.87252819], 
 [0.97711028 0.98030547 0.9795793  ... 0.86948629 0.87268113 0.87587604], 
 [0.97653759 0.97581362 0.9711683  ... 0.8610633  0.86818208 0.87530095]]
```

What I would like to to do is making it a channel that I can use in cv2.merge((r,g,b))
So that the float64 values per row get multiplied by 255 and something that cv2.merge() accepts.
I think NumPy can do such things but I'm confused, is there a way to do this?.

Comment: just `(arr * 256).astype('uint8')`?

Comment: @QuangHoang if there's any chance that the input will be `1.0` you should multiply by 255.99999 instead of 256 to prevent an overflow error.

Comment: or just multiply by 255 and use `np.round`, or `np.clip`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lets consider your three arrays to be `r` and `g` and `b` respectively. In such a case the following code should be what you need-

Edit-1: based on Mark's comment, I suggest the following changes

```py
r = (r*255).round(0).astype(np.uint8)
g = (g*255).round(0).astype(np.uint8)
b = (b*255).round(0).astype(np.uint8)

img = np.stack((r,g,b), axis=-1)
```

Edit-2: I may be wrong, but I'm not convinced that multiplying with 255.99999 is better. Doing so will result in many other pixel values getting bumped to the next value than they are originally or were supposed to be, here is small example I could come up with

```sh
# random fraction values
a:  [3.2000e-04 5.5111e-01 9.9999e-01 9.8850e-01]

a*255.99999:  [8.19199968e-02 1.41084154e+02 2.55997430e+02 2.53055990e+02]
(a*255.99999).astype(np.uint8):  [  0 141 255 253] 

a*255:  [8.1600000e-02 1.4053305e+02 2.5499745e+02 2.5206750e+02]
(a*255).round(0).astype(np.uint8):  [  0 141 255 252]
```

Additionally, I tied another small experiment with all possible pixel values and this surprisingly tells that both the methods are accurate

```py
pixels = np.arange(256, dtype=np.float64)
pixels /= 255

print(sum((pixels*255.99999).astype(np.uint8) == np.arange(256)))
# output is 256
print(sum((pixels*255).round(0).astype(np.uint8) == np.arange(256)))
# output is 256
```

Comment: I prefer to multiply by 255.9999 instead of 255, otherwise 255 will be very under represented in the output.

Comment: No, rounding is not better.  Now both 0 and 255 are under represented.

Comment: Is it possible to confirm somehow with an example? @MarkRansom

Comment: if you have a critique of this answer, you need to step forward and justify your reasoning. proposing to use a magic number puts you at a disadvantage.

Comment: @sai multiply by 256, then `np.clip`. in principle, the range [0..1) gets mapped to [0..256) (factor of 256), and if there happen to be 1.0 values that map to 256, just clip them to 255. to answer this **properly**, we would have to know how those float values were generated in the first place.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I completely agree with you, I am open to learn and defend what I think might be right. I also agree about the need to know how the factional values are initially generated in the first place.

Comment: @MarkRansom Could you comment on my findings?

Comment: Converting to integer values requires ranges on the real number line to be converted.  For the first case, multiplying by 255 and truncating, each of those ranges has a width of 1/255 except the last one for 255, which has a range of 0.  With rounding most ranges are still 1/255 in width, except the first and last which are now both 0.5/255.

Comment: Your newly added test case doesn't tell you what you think it does.  It's a lot easier to make integers round-trip convert than it is to convert arbitrary real values.

Comment: Try testing with `pixels = np.arange(1024, dtype=np.float64) / 1024` and what I'm saying may become clear.

Comment: Well in my case multiply by 255 seams right, my floats are in the 0 to 1 range.
so at max they can be 255 and at a minimum 0, there are some other values and filtersin opencvt for contrast and brightnes which will eventually be used as well.

Comment: @user219279 compare the odds of getting an output of 255 with the odds of getting an output of 254.

Comment: i changed it to 255.999 visually there was no difference for the eyes.